# How should I think about this subset of a product of projective lines?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, projective-geometry

Consider the group $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})$, and it maximal torus $T$ of invertible diagonal matrices. The coset space $G/T$ should have the structure of a (smooth?) variety/scheme/manifold. Direct computation shows that $G/T$ can be described as the space

$$ G/T = \{([a:b], [c:d]) \in \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \mid ad - bc \neq 0\}$$

How should I think about this space? For example, there seem to be many line bundles over this space that have an infinite-dimensional space of sections, as I found by attempting to induce characters from $T$ up to $G$, but I'm not sure of the reason for this geometrically. I'm also having trouble with some basic questions: is it connected? And importantly, where can I learn the theory required to understand this? (At least at an "intuitive" level).

Comment: There are the elements of the form $\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}1& b \\ c & bc+1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1& 0 \\ c & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1& b \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and some other like $\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix}0& 1 \\ -1 & d\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more detailed answer : there is a natural projection map $p : G/T \to \Bbb P^1$, projecting onto the first component. The fiber over $(a:b)$ is $\Bbb P^1 \backslash \{(a:b)\}$.

Such map has a nice interpretation : if $B$ is the group of upper-triangular matrices, $G/B$ can be interpreted as the complete flag variety in $\Bbb C^2$ i.e $\Bbb P^1$. The canonical map $G/T \to G/B \cong \Bbb P^1$ exhibits $G/T$ as a $B/T \cong \Bbb C$-bundle over $G/B \cong \Bbb P^1$.

This automatically shows you that $G/T$ is connected. Alternatively one could also embbed $Q = \Bbb P^1 \times \Bbb P^1$ in $\Bbb P^3$ as a quadric surface via the Segre embedding, and $G/T$ should correspond to the complement of an hyperplane section of $Q$ which is connected.

Now the tricky part comes, computing which bundle is $G/T \to G/B$. My guess is a correct approch would use something like Borel-Weil theorem (in fact the chapter about homogenous spaces in "Representation theory, a first course" by Fulton and Harris looks very nice, maybe it's a good place to looks even if they essentially look at $G/B$ for $B$ a Borel subgroup) and identify it nicely.

Since any bundle over $\Bbb P^1$ is $\mathcal O(k)$ we just need to check how many zeroes/poles has a generic section. I pick $\sigma : G/B \to G/T, (a,b) \mapsto ((a,b);(-b,a))$. This map is a rational section, with only two poles at $(1, \pm i)$. This means that $G/T \to G/B$ is the cotangent bundle of $\Bbb P^1$, namely $\mathcal O(-2)$.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer! I went and computed which $B$-representation the bundle $G/T \to G/B$ comes from (in the Borel-Weil sense), got a consistent answer: the character is $(-1, 1)$, the dual of $(1, -1)$ which I know to give the bundle $\mathcal{O}(2)$.

Comment: @Joppy : Thanks, this is very nice that you could deduce the results using representation theory. In fact your comment motivated me to learn more about this theorem, do you have a good reference for learn more about this ?

Comment: There are some lovely lectures by Joel Kamnitzer which contain examples of this construction: https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0569. Fulton's "Young Tableaux" contains a construction of the irreps of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ as line bundles on the flag variety. Jantzen's "Representations of Algebraic Groups" has a discussion valid for any algebraic group, but assumes a lot more of the reader, and has almost no examples.

Comment: @Joppy : this looks perfect, thanks a lot !